# SIMBA Amazon Athena JDBC driver causes LogFactoryImpl does not implement org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

Tags: jdbc, amazon-athena, simba

As of 2.0.31 to current (2.0.35), it appears that SIMBA did not shade logging as they had in prior releases such as 2.0.28. Appears to be a SIMBA (InsightSoftware) defect, is anyone aware of them having an open defect for this?

Up to 2.0.28, the SIMBA driver distributed by Amazon could be present on the classpath. As of 2.0.31+ when it is present it causes

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: Class org.apache.logging.log4j.jcl.LogFactoryImpl does not implement org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
                at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.verifyAncestory(ClassUtils.java:180)
                at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.verifyAncestory(SPInterface.java:201)
                at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.newInstance(SPInterface.java:195)
                at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.newInstance(DiscoverClass.java:579)
                at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:418)
                at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:378)
                at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
```